# Render post HTML response in Postman

Tags: html, http-post, postman

I am using Postman v4.9.3 and I am trying to view page response using POST request. Problem is that when clicking *Preview* button external CSS is not loaded. Can someone help me to resolve it? Or is there any other way to request page using POST and setting some headers and later rendering returned page?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like *Postman* will render HTML page good only if there is fully specified resources links in page.

So `/css/styles.css` will not work while `http://example.com/css/styles.css` will work.

Comment: It would be so easy for them to just add the domain name ...

Answer (score 1):

After hours of search I found [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/download) which does **exactly** what I want which is rendering CSS (even if the path is relative) in the "preview" mode.
Can't recommend it enough.

Answer (score 0):

Here https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/1048 it's told there is a workaround - you need to switch off the Interceptor extension.

Yet, if you use the desktop app you might not be able to do it.

I have both, desktop and chrome apps and disabling the Interceptor didn't help for me.

Maybe it's because I still have it in the desktop app.

Hope the solution will help for you, please send your feedback.

Comment: Unfortunately I am using only Desktop app.

Comment: Then I guess there is no solution yet.